# PHP, prevent javascript from running /delete javascript or php code written by user in a form

Tags: php, html, sql, xss

I am making a website where people will publish an article.
I make them write their article in a textarea, but I don't want them to add javascript, php or any other langage than html  to prevent XSS or SQL injections.
I'm trying to delete javascript or php code written by user in a form
How can I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: How is it a duplicate? I'm trying to delete javascript or php code written by user in a form?

Answer (score 0):

Just cut out all the `<script>` tags and don't execute the string from the `<textarea>` element (and use single quotes only). Against SQL injection you can use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to escape all SQL special characters.

Comment: How do I cut them out? @G_hi3